# Raspberry Pi 2 Java - Cannot load mainclass/ ClassNotFound WebView

Tags: java, webview, javafx, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to run a simple FavaFX App on my Raspberry Pi 2 running the newest Raspbian.
With the standard Java version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

The App starts and this error shows up

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.web.WebView
```

And with this Java Version:

```
$ /opt/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

This Error:

```
 $ /opt/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java -jar MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
 Error: Could not find or load main class org.my.app.Main
```

The App simply opens a WebView. On My laptop it works just fine.

If you need more information please let me know! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>First error seems this is a [headless Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) runtime.</strike>  Right now I'm reading WebView isn't supported: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=69350&p=553602.

Second error seems your JAR is not correctly build or at least do not contains `org/my/app/Main.java`. Check with a ZIP tool that the class is in.

Comment: I am using the same .jar file in both cases, the Main file exists because it is working with the other java version. And the same jar file works on my laptop

Comment: Hard to believe you do it the same way in both cases and `jdk1.8.0_60` won't find the main class, even it is exists. You hit an important bug or something is different in the usage.

Comment: Looks like they dropped JavaFX support and maybe thats why jdk1.8 .0_60 cannot find my Main class. https://jaxenter.de/ende-javafx-embedded-13340